# Linq : How to sorting by date strine values in IQueryable .Net6?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I have a table where users are stored and I want to display them by date,Dates are stored as strings.

Linq :

```cs
IQueryable<User> result = _context.Users
    .AsQueryable()
    .Include(r => r.Role)
    .Include(u => u.UserDetail)
    .Where(u => u.Role.RoleName != "Admin")
    .OrderByDescending(u => DateTime.Parse(u.UserDetail.RegisterDate));
```

I used the above code but it didn't display sorted!!!
I also checked the following link, but my problem was not solved?
[Sorting IQueryable date column by string value in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792602/sorting-iqueryable-date-column-by-string-value-in-linq)

Comment: How date is stored in database (string is too generalized)? Which SQL function can convert to date? Which EF Core version?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv EF6

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv EF Core6 works with .NET6 .. I mentioned it in the title of my question

Comment: Then answer for first question. How dates are stored? In which format? Maybe better to sort on the client side?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv date as string format

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I can sort without IQueryable, but not with this

Comment: What database provider are you using? With SQL Server, you could use `EF.Functions.DateTime2FromParts` and `Substring` to extract the year, month and day, cast to `int` and convert to a `DateTime`.

Comment: It seems like another possibility to try is to do `OrderByDescending(u => (DateTime)(object)u.UserDetail.RegisterDate)` to translate to a SQL CAST.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using TryParse, which is a more forgiving method than "ParseExact"

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(result.UserDetail.RegisterDate, out registerDate))
{
    result = result.OrderByDescending(u => registerDate);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use ParseExact like so;

```
try
{
    result = result.OrderByDescending(u => 
        DateTime.ParseExact(u.UserDetail.RegisterDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    
}
```

Keep in mind ParseExact is very strict and can throw FormatException if you don't provide exactly correct inputs.
I would suggest changing the type of the column to DateTime instead of String in future whenever you can, as it will make the application more maintainable, and sorting will be faster that way.

To apply either technique, simply do what you were doing without the "OrderByDescending" at its end like so;

```
IQueryable<User> result = _context.Users.AsQueryable().Include(r=> 
    r.Role).Include(u => u.UserDetail).Where(u=> u.Role.RoleName != 
    "Admin");
```

and apply either technique afterwards.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'm sure `ParseExact` will fail with EF Core also.

Comment: ParseExact is a method of DateTime Class. it just takes string and outputs DateTime, there is no reason for it not to work with LINQ

Comment: You don't understand how LINQ to databases works than, specifically LINQ to EF / EF Core. Instead of calling methods directly, LINQ to databases translates a LINQ expression into a database query (typically in SQL) and than runs that query on the database. It can only translate methods it understands. This is different for different database providers. See [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#date-and-time-functions) for SQL Server with EF Core, and note `TryParse` and `ParseExact` are not included.

Comment: of course, TryParse and ParseExact are not included in the EF Core documentation, because these methods are from the DateTime class. if you check my code again, you will see I am not generating database queries with these methods. I first take the result from the database (which is enumerable), and only then I employ these parsing methods using LINQ, at which point EF/database is not anymore involved/concerned. a foreach loop could also be used instead of LINQ, which would also work fine.